# Get RichTextBox Format and use it for a replace function

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I just started to learn VB and try to make a little WYSIWYG-HTML Editor. For that i already made a RichTextBox in which the user is able to change colour, fontsize etc.. Now I want to add for example a `<b>` -Tag before and a `</b>` -Tag after a word which is written in bold style, save it in a string and give back the new string in a second read-only-Textbox.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Please, post your code (or a representative sample of it) to see what you have done sofar and how you are facing the problems.

Answer (score -1):

So you want to set read-only textbox's text to the richtextbox's text and then replace certain string with other strings?

If so, here's some code I wrote up. It's probably not the best but it works.

```
TextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text 'Copies the text form the richtextbox to the normal textbox

    If TextBox1.Text.Contains("<b>") Then 'Checks to see if Textbox1 contains the string "<b>"
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("<b>", "[b]") 'Replaces <b> with [b]
    End If

    If RichTextBox1.Text.Contains("</b>") Then 'Same thing as above but this checks to see if it contains "</b>"
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("</b>", "[/b]")
    End If
```